# How to replace a column in a file matching to another column

Tags: awk

I have two files. How to replace the second column in file 2 with column 12 in file 1 in such a way that column 9 in file 1 is the same as column 1 in file 2?

file1

```
    1 2000 11 11  7  9 45  840                         49667.8048  18.33  HeI  6.10352e-05
    2 2000 11 11  8 56 57  660                         49667.8782  18.15  HeI   0.00546265
    3 1994 11 12  5 18 10 1020                         49668.7284  18.34  HeI  -0.00497437
    4 1994 11 12  7 35 30  840                         49668.8227  18.14  HeI  -0.00357056
    5 1994 11 12  9  6 42  720                         49668.8854  17.99  HeI  -0.00476074
    6 1994 11 14  5 20 43  600                         49670.7279  18.04  HeI  -0.00326538
    7 1994 11 14  7 32 46  630                         49670.8197  17.84  HeI  -0.00598145
    8 3000 11 14  9 21 14  540                         49670.8945  17.66  HeI   0.00701904
    9 1994 11 15  5 21 14  610                         49671.7283  17.88  HeI  -0.00100708
   10 4445 11 15  7  4  5  540                         49671.7994  17.73  HeI  -0.00503540
   11 1994 11 15  9  1 14  600                         49671.8811  17.53  HeI     0.000000
   12 1996  1 11  0 56  4  301                         50093.5444   2.26  HeI   0.00570679
   13 1996  1 11  1  2 30  601                         50093.5506   2.25  HeI   0.00424194
   14 1996  1 11  1 15 23  541                         50093.5592   2.23  HeI   0.00100708
   15 1996  1 11  1 26 29  420                         50093.5662   2.22  HeI   0.00372314
```

file2

```
49667.8048   78.450     3.000     1    1
49667.8782   79.900     1.000     1    1
49668.7284   40.890     1.000     1    1
49668.8227   45.790     1.000     1    1
49668.8854   49.770     5.000     1    1
49670.7279   66.060     1.000     1    1
49670.8197   47.380     1.000     1    1
49670.8945   27.270     6.000     1    1
49671.7283   66.190     1.000     1    1
49671.7994   65.320     6.000     1    1
49671.8811   62.290     1.000     1    1
```

Desired result:

```
49667.8048   6.10352e-05     3.000     1    1
49667.8782   0.00546265      1.000     1    1
49668.7284   -0.00497437     1.000     1    1
49668.8227   -0.00357056     1.000     1    1
49668.8854   -0.00476074     5.000     1    1
......
```

I tried something like

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ar[$9]=$0;next}($1 in ar){print ar[$9],$0}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ar[$9]=$12;next}
($1 in ar) {$2= ar[$1]}1'  file1 file2
```

In this command, `NR==FNR{ar[NR]=$12;next}` means this rule will be for first file *only* because `FNR` would be set to zero after file1. In this rule an array `ar` is created with contents of field 12 indexed on field 9(`$9`) of first file `file1`. `next` prevents further action on `file1`.

The expression `if ($1 in ar) $2=ar[$1]` means if first field(`$1`) in found in *indices* of `ar` then it changes second field of `file2` to `ar`. This is because `ar` in indexed on $9 of first file `file1`. Because `$2` of `file2` is changed now, `1` will print new `$0`.

And `1` is `awk`'s idiom for print.

Comment: Thank you very much and how to do the loop over files when the second input file is that over loop is running?

`for f in rv*.dat; do 
    awk 'NR==FNR{ar[NR]=$12;next} {for (i=1;i<=length(ar);i++) if (FNR==i) $2=ar[i]}1' cat43_BVS "$f" > temp
done`
How to use $f in this case?

Comment: @ElenaGreg  `for f in rv*.dat; do      awk 'NR==FNR{ar[NR]=$12;next} {for (i=1;i<=length(ar);i++) if (FNR==i) $2=ar[i]}1' cat43_BVS "$f" > ${f}.new done`. If you don't want new files, then you could do inplace editing fo file with `-i inplace` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Since your files are sorted, this can be done with the `join` command:

```
join file1 file2 -1 9 -2 1 -o 2.1,1.12,2.3,2.4,2.5
```

Explanation:

- The two files are joined on the column #9 of file1 (`-1` option) and the column #1 of file2 (`-2` option)
- The output (`-o`) option is made from fields 2.1 (1st column of file2), 1.12 (12th column of file1), etc.

Comment: +1.  Good explanation.

Comment: Thank you @PrabhjotSingh!