# Replacing column using awk

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I ran the following code to [replace the second columns of two files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653310/377345) (`file2` and `file3`) with column 12 from file `source.dat`, based on the 9th column of `source.dat` that should match to the first columns of `file2` and `file3`.

So far, I tried

```bsh
for f in fil*; do 
    awk 'NR==FNR{ar[NR]=$12;next} {for (i=1;i<=length(ar);i++) if (FNR==i) $2=ar[i]}1' source.dat "$f" > temp
    awk '{printf("%.4f %12.8f     1.000     1    1\n", $1, $2)}' temp > "${f}_bvs"
done
```

Output from `file2` is correct except for containing an extra line in the end; however, the output for `file3` contains other values in the second column. What is wrong, please?

- source.dat

  ```
      1 2000 11 11  7  9 45  840                         49667.8048  18.33  HeI  6.10352e-05
      2 2000 11 11  8 56 57  660                         49667.8782  18.15  HeI   0.00546265
      3 1994 11 12  5 18 10 1020                         49668.7284  18.34  HeI  -0.00497437
      4 1994 11 12  7 35 30  840                         49668.8227  18.14  HeI  -0.00357056
      5 1994 11 12  9  6 42  720                         49668.8854  17.99  HeI  -0.00476074
      6 1994 11 14  5 20 43  600                         49670.7279  18.04  HeI  -0.00326538
      7 1994 11 14  7 32 46  630                         49670.8197  17.84  HeI  -0.00598145
      8 3000 11 14  9 21 14  540                         49670.8945  17.66  HeI   0.00701904
      9 1994 11 15  5 21 14  610                         49671.7283  17.88  HeI  -0.00100708
     10 4445 11 15  7  4  5  540                         49671.7994  17.73  HeI  -0.00503540
     11 1994 11 15  9  1 14  600                         49671.8811  17.53  HeI     0.000000
     12 1996  1 11  0 56  4  301                         50093.5444   2.26  HeI   0.00570679
     13 1996  1 11  1  2 30  601                         50093.5506   2.25  HeI   0.00424194
     14 1996  1 11  1 15 23  541                         50093.5592   2.23  HeI   0.00100708
     15 1996  1 11  1 26 29  420                         50093.5662   2.22  HeI   0.00372314
  ```
- file2

  ```
  49667.8048   78.450     3.000     1    1
  49667.8782   79.900     1.000     1    1
  49668.7284   40.890     1.000     1    1
  49668.8227   45.790     1.000     1    1
  49668.8854   49.770     5.000     1    1
  49670.7279   66.060     1.000     1    1
  49670.8197   47.380     1.000     1    1
  49670.8945   27.270     6.000     1    1
  49671.7283   66.190     1.000     1    1
  49671.7994   65.320     6.000     1    1
  49671.8811   62.290     1.000     1    1
  ```
- file3

  ```
  50093.5444   13.480     1.000     1    1
  50093.5506   14.830     1.000     1    1
  50093.5592   12.150     1.000     1    1
  50093.5662   12.150     1.000     1    1
  ```

Current output

- for file2

  ```
  49667.8048   0.00006104     1.000     1    1
  49667.8782   0.00546265     1.000     1    1
  49668.7284  -0.00497437     1.000     1    1
  49668.8227  -0.00357056     1.000     1    1
  49668.8854  -0.00476074     1.000     1    1
  49670.7279  -0.00326538     1.000     1    1
  49670.8197  -0.00598145     1.000     1    1
  49670.8945   0.00701904     1.000     1    1
  49671.7283  -0.00100708     1.000     1    1
  49671.7994  -0.00503540     1.000     1    1
  49671.8811   0.00000000     1.000     1    1
  0.0057   0.00000000     1.000     1    1
  ```
- for file3

  ```
  50093.5444   0.00006104     1.000     1    1
  50093.5506   0.00546265     1.000     1    1
  50093.5592  -0.00497437     1.000     1    1
  50093.5662  -0.00357056     1.000     1    1
  ```

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate since I don't see any difference with your previous question: [How to replace a column in a file matching to another column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653310/how-to-replace-a-column-in-a-file-matching-to-another-column)

Comment: I need this question to solve some problems with more specific code.

Comment: The question is the same and the accepted answer is just a variation of the accepted answer there, which would equally work here. The only difference is that file1 and file2 have been swapped. This is the very definition of a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that using `join`:

```
~$ join -1 1 -2 9 -o 1.1,2.12,1.3,1.4,1.5 file2 source.dat 
49667.8048 6.10352e-05 3.000 1 1
49667.8782 0.00546265 1.000 1 1
49668.7284 -0.00497437 1.000 1 1
49668.8227 -0.00357056 1.000 1 1
49668.8854 -0.00476074 5.000 1 1
49670.7279 -0.00326538 1.000 1 1
49670.8197 -0.00598145 1.000 1 1
49670.8945 0.00701904 6.000 1 1
49671.7283 -0.00100708 1.000 1 1
49671.7994 -0.00503540 6.000 1 1
49671.8811 0.000000 1.000 1 1

~$ join -1 1 -2 9 -o 1.1,2.12,1.3,1.4,1.5 file3 source.dat
50093.5444 0.00570679 1.000 1 1
50093.5506 0.00424194 1.000 1 1
50093.5592 0.00100708 1.000 1 1
50093.5662 0.00372314 1.000 1 1
```

This will instruct `join` to match `file2` (or `file3`) as first file and `source.dat` as second file on columns 1 and 9, respectively (`-1 1 -2 9`) and output the first column of the first file, the 12th from the second, and then the remaining ones (except the original column 2) from the first file.

**Edit**

It seems that this is a follow-up question to [a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653310/377345), and that you want to implement this using `awk`. In that case, try

```
~$ awk 'FNR==NR{v[$9]=$12;next} {print $1,v[$1],$3,$4,$5}' source.dat file2 
49667.8048 6.10352e-05 3.000 1 1
49667.8782 0.00546265 1.000 1 1
49668.7284 -0.00497437 1.000 1 1
49668.8227 -0.00357056 1.000 1 1
49668.8854 -0.00476074 5.000 1 1
49670.7279 -0.00326538 1.000 1 1
49670.8197 -0.00598145 1.000 1 1
49670.8945 0.00701904 6.000 1 1
49671.7283 -0.00100708 1.000 1 1
49671.7994 -0.00503540 6.000 1 1
49671.8811 0.000000 1.000 1 1

~$  awk 'FNR==NR{v[$9]=$12;next} {print $1,v[$1],$3,$4,$5}' source.dat file3
50093.5444 0.00570679 1.000 1 1
50093.5506 0.00424194 1.000 1 1
50093.5592 0.00100708 1.000 1 1
50093.5662 0.00372314 1.000 1 1
```

Or, in a loop

```
for f in file*; do awk 'FNR==NR{v[$9]=$12;next} {print $1,v[$1],$3,$4,$5}' source.dat "$f" > "${f}_bvs"; done
```